# Column references in formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am a little stuck at the moment.  I am working on an array of data and need to find a way to input column numbers into formulas.

-I have used the match function to find the corresponding column number for a value. 
     ex. "XYZ" matched with `Column 3`, which is equivalent to `C1:Cxxxxxx`

-now for inputing the `C1:Cxxxxxx` into a formula to get data for that particular column, I would like to be able to directly reference the `Column 3` part, because I plan on using this workbook in the future and the column needed to run the calculation may or may not be column 3 the next time I use it.
- is there any way to tell excel to  use a formula to tell excel which column to use for an equation?

so a little more detail, I have the equation

```
=AND(Sheet3!$C$1:$C$250000=$A$4,Sheet3!$B$1:$B$250000=$B$4)
```

instead of specifying to use column C, is there a way to use a formula to tell it to use C?

EDIT: more additional info;
"i am basically running the equivalent of a SQL where statement where foo and bar are true, I want excel to spit out a concatenated list of all baz values where foo and bar are true. ideally i would like it to ONLY return baz values that are true, then I will concat them together separately. the way I got it now, the expression will test every row separately to see if true; if there is 18K rows, there will be 18K separate tests.. it works, but it's not too clean.  the goal is to have as much automated as possible. **i do not want to have to go in and change the column references every time I add a new data arra**y"

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the ``COLUMN`` function?

Comment: yes, column will just return the column value (a number).  I want to be able to use that value in another formula to replace Sheet3!$C$1:$C$250000, in other words it will be automated so i will not have to change it every time.

Comment: i will give a little more background; i am basically running the equivalent of a SQL where statement where foo and bar are true, I want excel to spit out a concatenated list of all baz values where foo and bar are true.   ideally i would like it to ONLY return baz values that are true, then I will concat them together separately.  the way I got it now, the expression will test every row separately to see if true; if there is 18K rows, there will be 18K separate tests.. it works, but it's not too clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`, e.g. if you have 26 possible columns from A to Z then this formula will give you your column C range (which you can use in another formula)

`=INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$Z$250000,0,3)`

The 0 indicates that you want the whole column, the 3 indicates which column. If you want the 3 can be generated by another formula like a `MATCH` function

Note: be careful with AND in

`=AND(Sheet3!$C$1:$C$250000=$A$4,Sheet3!$B$1:$B$250000=$B$4)`

`AND` only returns a single result not an array, if you want an array you might need to use * like this

`=(Sheet3!$C$1:$C$250000=$A$4)*(Sheet3!$B$1:$B$250000=$B$4)`

Comment: i'm pretty sure the "and" is doing it's job the best way I know of.. yes, it basically calculates for every cell (so if i have 14000 rows of data the AND function will have to go 14000 rows) but that is the best way i can think of doing it.. ideally, the formula would ONLY return values that test "true" by the AND, but i'm not sure how to do that..

Comment: and good idea on the index,,0,x I did not know that 0's in index refer to the whole column.. this might be useful, i will test it out

Comment: The AND formula, as you have it written, will return a single result (not one for each row) and that result will always be FALSE unless every value in Sheet3!$C$1:$C$250000 is equal to $A$4 and also every value in Sheet3!$B$1:$B$250000 is equal to $B$4. I suspect you don't want to do that - if you want an "array" of TRUE/FALSE results you need to do it the way I suggested

Comment: the AND result returns a single result per row.  it does work on an array; for example- if the array has 20 rows of data, and you use this AND function, it will give you the data for each individual row.  if you copy the formula down 20 cells, it will test FALSE on the rows that don't meet the conditions and TRUE on the rows that meet the conditions.  there is no need to make it an array function Ctrl+shift+enter.  just hit enter like a regular formula and drag down 20 rows.  the only problem with this is it gets a little messy if there are many rows, i would like to find a way to only (cont)

Comment: ...return rows that test true.  that way if there is 18K rows of data, i don't need to stretch the formula down the full 18K rows

Comment: It dawned on me eventually that you were doing that....but it's not good practice  - if you want a formula to copy down then you should just reference one cell, e.g. like this `=AND(Sheet3!C1=$A$4,Sheet3!B1=$B$4)`......but if you want a count of rows that match you can do that with a single formula, `=COUNTIFS(Sheet3!C:C,A4,Sheet3!B:B,B4)` and any of the columns in that can be replaced with my INDEX suggestion if the column isn't fixed

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ADDRESS` to generate the text, you then need to use `INDIRECT` as you are passing a string rather than a range to the fomula

`=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,3,,,"Sheet3") & ":" & ADDRESS(250000,3))=$A$4
    ,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,2,,,"Sheet3") & ":" & ADDRESS(250000,2))=$B$4)`

Obviously replace the 3s and 2s in the `ADDRESS` formulae with your `MATCH` function you used to get the column number. The above assumes the column for $B$1:$B$25000 is also found using `MATCH', otherwise it is just:

`=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,3,,,"Sheet3") & ":" & ADDRESS(250000,3))=$A$4
    ,Sheet3!$B$1:$B$25000=$B$4)`

Note a couple of things:

1. You only need to use "Sheet3" on the first part of the `INDRECT`
2. Conditions 3 and 4 in the `ADDRESS` formula are left as default, this
   means they return absolute ($C$1) reference and are A1 style as
   opposed to R1C1

**EDIT**

Given the additional info maybe using an advanced filter would get you near to what you want. Good tutorial [here](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2012/06/20/learn-excel-advanced-filters.aspx). Set it up according to the tutorial to familiarise yourself with it and then you can use some basic code to set it up automatically when you drop in a new dataset:

Paste in the dataset and then use VBA to get the range the dataset uses then apply the filter with something like:

`Range("A6:F480").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B3"), Unique:=False`

You can also copy the results into a new table, though this has to be in the same sheet as the original data. My suggestion would be paste you data into hidden columns to the left and put space for your criteria in rows 1:5 of the visible columns and then have a button that gets the used range for your data, applies the filter and copies the data below the criteria:

`Range("A6:F480").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets _
        Range("H1:M3"), CopyToRange:=Range("H6"), Unique:=False`

Button would need to clear the destination cells first etc, make sure you have enough hidden columns etc but it's all possible. Hope this helps.